# Jupyter error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyterlab'"

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, modulenotfounderror

After updating to Ubuntu LTS 22.04 the usual code "jupyter lab" is no more working.

Here what I get instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "/home/lorenzo/.local/bin/jupyter-lab", line 5, in <module>
      from jupyterlab.labapp import main 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyterlab'
```

I tried to dig into related old questions but I didn't manage to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: What is the result of `pip list` and `jupyter --version`?

Comment: The pip list is very long, is there something shouldn't miss?

Comment: the jupyter version is: Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.4.0
ipykernel        : 6.15.2
ipywidgets       : 8.0.2
jupyter_client   : 7.3.5
jupyter_core     : 4.11.1
jupyter_server   : 1.18.1
jupyterlab       : 3.4.6
nbclient         : 0.6.7
nbconvert        : 7.0.0
nbformat         : 5.4.0
notebook         : 6.4.12
qtconsole        : 5.3.2
traitlets        : 5.3.0

Comment: I do not know why it is happening, but here is a hypothesis: It might be that the Python version has changed but the files in your `~/.local/bin` were not updated to use the shebang pointing to the new version. What is in your `/home/lorenzo/.local/bin/jupyter-lab`? The first line should include a shebang like `#!/path/to/some/python/version` - is this the version you would expect/which has JupyterLab installed?

Comment: The first line gives "#!/usr/bin/python3". 

How can I check if this is the right version?

Comment: you can check if it is the same as `which python` and also manually check if `/usr/bin/python3` includes jupyterlab installation via: `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip list | grep jupyter`. Also checking `which jupyter` may be useful to triangulate.

Comment: If I run `/usr/bin/python3 -m pip list | grep jupyter`, I get: " jupyter                1.0.0
jupyter_client         7.3.5
jupyter-console        6.4.4
jupyter-core           4.11.1
jupyter-server         1.18.1
jupyterlab             3.4.6
jupyterlab-pygments    0.2.2
jupyterlab_server      2.15.1
jupyterlab-widgets     3.0.3
"

Comment: the jupyter version  `jupyter notebook --version` gives "6.4.12"

Comment: So `pip` confirms that you do have jupyterlab installed for that Python version (or it thinks so). Interesting. One more thing to check to ensure the installation is not the problem: what is the result of  `/usr/bin/python3 -c 'import jupyterlab.labapp; print(jupyterlab.labapp.main)'`?

Comment: It returns "<bound method ExtensionApp.launch_instance of <class 'jupyterlab.labapp.LabApp'>>"

Answer (score 10):

The issue should be solved by updating `jupyterlab`, in your case by

```
pip install jupyterlab --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your python version is 2.x which comes with ubuntu, if so you need to switch to 3.x